# MAT-File API using C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, mex

I have problem running "Read MAT-File in C/C++" from MATLAB examples.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/creating-a-mat-file-in-c.html

- When I compile it from the MATLAB command window using MEX, everything is fine and the MATLAB MAT file is created.
- When I use the same MSVC compiler parameters in command line, everything works fine.
- When I create a simple console application in VS2015 and setup the project to use the MATLAB MAT-File API (includes, libs, etc.), everything works,

However, when I try to setup my QT application project to use the MATLAB MAT-File API, it builds, but running the app gives me this error:

[image: error]

I'm using MATLAB 2016a and Visual Studio 2015 Community with Qt5.6 plugin on Win10 64-bit. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Seems to come from Unicode conversion code (an error callback). First google results: http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/converters. Dunno if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some more "research" on that. I'll let you know..